# Настройка портов для nginx

Tags: nginx

Я хочу сделать из своего второго компа хостинг для сайта, сайт на Django, буду делать на nginx. вопрос вот в чем: надо будет залезать в настройки роутера, чтобы он запросы по определенным портам (80 например или 443) отправлял на конкретный комп в этой локальной сети или там само все сделается?

Comment: Это зависит не от nginx, а от того, как устроена ваша сеть, и если вы задаёте такой вопрос, то скорее всего надо

Comment: А ещё провайдер должен выдать «белый» IP и не блокировать порты 80/443.